# How do I replace the first occurance of a key value in a config file with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to change the application name in a config file. `Name=` has multiple occurrences, but I only want to change the first. For reference, the config file has the following structure:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=name
Name[ar]=...
[...]
[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
[...]
```

What I tried so far is the bash command sed:

```
sudo sed "0,/Name/s/=.*\$/=Replace/" app_desktop_configs/std_firefox.desktop
```

which mostly did what I wanted, **but** also replaces the version number:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=Replace
Name=Replace
Name[ar]=...
[...]
```

Alternative solution to sed are also welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So match exactly `Name=` not `=.*`

```
sed '0,/^Name=/s/^Name=.*/Name=Replace/'
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `'0,/Name=.*/s//Name=Replace/'`

Comment: This can be further shortened to `sed '0,/\(Name=\).*/s//\1Replace/' input_file`

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'unless ( $cnt ) { s{Name=name}{Name=replace} and $cnt++; } ' infile
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/(name=).*/{s//\1Replace/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

Or:

```
sed -E 's/(name=).*/\1Replace/;T;:a;n;ba' file
```

Or:

```
sed  -E 'x;/./{x;b};x;/(name=).*/h;s//\1Replace/' file
```

All the above solutions amend the first occurrence of `name` and then continue to the end of the file making no further amendments.